# Can I get attractive list of users filtered by reputation?

Tags: support

I want to get list of users filtered according to their TOTAL reputations.

For Example: (this is only example can be filtered by any quota which looks standard top list)

1. n1 users >= 20k reputations
2. n2 users >= 10k reputations
3. n3 users >= 5k reputations
4. n3 users >= 1k reputations
5. n3 users >= 500 reputations
6. n3 users >= 100 reputations
7. n3 users >= 20 reputations
8. n4 users < 20 reputations

Where n1, n2 ,..... are number of users

Comment: Not sure if this enough, [but SE stats](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/31/alltime/askubuntu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can see Stack Exchange Leagues for askubuntu [here.](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/31/alltime/askubuntu)

It also shows ranks with-respect-to All-time Reputations.
[image: top users from stack-exchange]

Table of users with total reputation is also there:

[image: table of number of users w.r.t total reputations]

@Dan suggested.